# Ansible 1.8.2 nested loop, trying to output item[1] in item[0] string, but its being escaped

Tags: ansible

Here is my example, not sure if this can be done, but I would like to output the value from the sites array, specifically item[1].site, in item[0].dest, but it looks like it is escaping {{ item[1].site }}, to {# item[1].site #}. Is there a way to prevent it from escaping the string?

```
- name: Put files into docker directory
  template: src={{ item[0].src }}  dest={{ item[0].src }}
  with_nested:
    - [
        { src: 'Dockerfile.j2', dest: "/opt/docker-apache2-fpm/{{ item[1].site }}/Dockerfile" },
      ]
    - sites
```

Here is the output:

```
failed: [192.168.200.87] => (item=[{'dest': u'/opt/docker-apache2-fpm/{# item[1].site #}/Dockerfile', 'src': 'Dockerfile.j2'}, {'site': 'admin.mysite.com', 'user': 'mysite', 'uid': 11004}]) => {"failed": true, "item": [{"dest": "/opt/docker-apache2-fpm/{# item[1].site #}/Dockerfile", "src": "Dockerfile.j2"}, {"site": "admin.mysite.com", "uid": 11004, "user": "mysite"}]}
msg: Destination directory  does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not working, because Ansible is not re-evaluating the elements. But you can work with the [replace](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#replace) filter to archive your goal.

```
- name: Put files into docker directory
  template: src={{ item[0].src }}  dest={{ item[0].dest | replace("%site%", item[1].site) }}
  with_nested:
    - [
        { src: 'Dockerfile.j2', dest: "/opt/docker-apache2-fpm/%site%/Dockerfile" },
      ]
    - sites
```

In that example I assumed you meant `item[0].dest` and not `item[0].src` in your `dest` assignment.